# How to set a particular image to particular days within calendar within the app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, calendar

I studied about WPControl and I used calendar from this package.
I studied the [link](http://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) . I can able to give background color to particular days in the calendar. But I am unable to set the background image for that.

By the way, I am using this calendar to show some message details for that particular day.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/APPNAME;component/Images/IMAGENAME));
Object.Background = brush;
```

Just replace `APPNAME` and `IMAGENAME` with the respected fields.

Note: Replace any spaces under the `APPNAME` section of the code with %20.

Comment: Please can you tell me where to use this code and how to use..... I was little busy with some work thats why i didnt replied you.